# How to resolve "Warning: Could not decode event!"

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js, truffle

I have a smart contract for sending money user-to-user.

In this smart contract, I pass the smart contract address from the Kovan network when the user selects a coin.

In this case, I pass the ChainLink contract address to my contract for sending the Chain Link token to the user.

This is ChainLink contract address in the Kovan network: `0xa36085f69e2889c224210f603d836748e7dc0088`.

Now I want to test contract functions with this code:

```
const assert = require("assert");

const Dex = artifacts.require("Dex");

contract("Dex", (accounts) => {

    let dex;
    let contractOwner = null;
    let buyer = null;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        contractOwner = accounts[0];
        buyer = accounts[1];

        dex = await Dex.new();
        contractOwner = accounts[0];
        // sometimes you need to test a user except contract owner
        buyer = accounts[1];
    });

    // it("Add tokens and contract address Success", async () => {

    //     const tokenInfo = await dex.getTokenContractAddress("USDT");

    //     assert(tokenInfo == "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7");
    // })

    // it("Add Token", async () => {

    //     await dex.addToken(web3.utils.fromAscii("LINK"), "0xa36085f69e2889c224210f603d836748e7dc0088", "0xa36085f69e2889c224210f603d836748e7dc0088")


    // })
    it("Deposit", async () => {

        await dex.deposit("0xa36085f69e2889c224210f603d836748e7dc0088", "0x5226a51522C23CcBEFd04a2d4C6c8e281eD1d680", "0xB643992c9fBcb1Cb06b6C9eb278b2ac35e6a2711", 1,
            // you were missing this
            { from: accounts[0] });

    })



})
```

I Using Truffle in Project:

Truffle Config:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');

const fs = require('fs');
const mnemonic = fs.readFileSync(".secret").toString().trim();
const secrets = JSON.parse(
  fs.readFileSync('.secrets.json').toString().trim()
);

module.exports = {

  networks: {
    kovan: {
      networkCheckTimeout: 10000,
      provider: () => {
         return new HDWalletProvider(
          mnemonic,
           `https://kovan.infura.io/v3/1461728202954c07bd5ed5308641a054`,
           0,
           20
         );
      },
      network_id: "42",
   },
  },

  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters, etc.
  mocha: {
  
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.10", 
      docker: false, 
      settings: { 
        optimizer: {
          enabled: false,
          runs: 200
        },
        evmVersion: "byzantium"
      }
    }
  },
};
```

My Contract:

```
  // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

// import "./UserCoins.sol";

contract Dex {
    event Approval(
        address indexed tokenOwner,
        address indexed spender,
        uint256 tokens
    );
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 tokens);

    constructor() {}

    function deposit(
        address ticker,
     

   address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) external payable {
        IERC20 token = IERC20(ticker);
        IERC20(ticker).approve(sender, amount);
        // Transfer Token To User
        token.transferFrom(sender, recipient, amount);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    }

}
```

it shows me this error:

> Warning: Could not decode event!
> execution failed due to an exception. Reverted

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
function deposit(address ticker,address sender,address recipient,uint256 amount
                ) 
                external payable
```

this function takes 4 args, you passed all the parameters but since it is payable, you have to also make sure from which account you are calling, so you need to add 5th parameter to the function:

```
await dex.deposit("0xa36085f69e2889c224210f603d836748e7dc0088", "0x5226a51522C23CcBEFd04a2d4C6c8e281eD1d680", "0xB643992c9fBcb1Cb06b6C9eb278b2ac35e6a2711", "1",
// you were missing this
{from:accounts[0])
```

In truffle test suite, when you create the contract, it passes the `accounts` as the first argument to the callback. You have to define accounts in `before` statement so when you run the tests those will be available on top level.

```
contract("Dex", (accounts) => {
  let contractOwner = null;
  let buyer = null;
  let _contract = null;


  before(async () => {
      // Instead of Dex.new() try Dex.deployed()
      // I am not sure if "new()" is still supported
      _contract = await Dex.deployed();
      contractOwner = accounts[0];
      // sometimes you need to test a user except contract owner
      buyer = accounts[1];
  });

}
```

### You need to approve

Inside `ERC20.sol` you are calling this:

```
function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        uint256 currentAllowance = _allowances[sender][_msgSender()];
        if (currentAllowance != type(uint256).max) {
            require(currentAllowance >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance");
            unchecked {
                _approve(sender, _msgSender(), currentAllowance - amount);
            }
        }  
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);

        return true;
    }
```

So you want DEX to transfer coin from another contract. So this another contract has to approve this transaction first. So I need to have another contract's address to be able to call `approve`

Comment: where should I put `{from:account}` ?  I Try This `function Deposit(
        address ticker,
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount,
        {from:account}
    ) public` it show me error : `Expected type name`

Comment: @Kianoush I just updated

Comment: you dont need to set contractOwner or buyer  in this app you could just pass `accounts[0]. it might help as your app grows

Comment: still show me that error

Comment: I Try This :  `await dex.deposit("0xa36085f69e2889c224210f603d836748e7dc0088", accounts[5], accounts[4], "1")`

Comment: @Kianoush `function deposit(
        address ticker,
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount,
       {from:accounts[0]}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241655/discussion-between-kianoush-and-yilmaz).

Comment: i got new Error :) : ` json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field params.fromBlock of type string`

Comment: and this one : `The execution failed due to an exception.
Reverted`

Comment: try passing 1 instead of "1"

Comment: Not yet resolved

Comment: Hi again . did you find any answer ? i can not solve that yet .

Comment: What was the latest error :) I forgot where i I left off :)

Comment: `Warning: Could not decode event!` : this warning and after that show me this error : 
`The execution failed due to an exception.
Reverted`

Comment: Can you send me the github link. I will take a look later.  `execution failed due to an exception. Reverted` this can be for any reason

Comment: ok i will send it to you

Comment: https://github.com/kia9372/DEX/blob/main/test/dex.test.js

Comment: @Kianoush this is your test metamask right?

Comment: I Try To Use Kovan Testnet . these wallet `0x5226a51522C23CcBEFd04a2d4C6c8e281eD1d680` and `0xB643992c9fBcb1Cb06b6C9eb278b2ac35e6a2711` in metamask and kovan test net

Comment: @Kianoush please tell me this is your test metamask. You uploaded your mnemonics to github which is not safe.

Comment: yes this just for test .

Comment: Even though it is for test, always put your configuration files info into the .gitignore. so it will be pshed to github. people are watching github repos with configs

Comment: For th e security, delete your github repo, att secrets.json to gitignore and then upload it again if you want to

Comment: ok . i will informed you for new repository

Comment: @Kianoush I already have your repo

Comment: https://github.com/kia9372/DEX/blob/main/contracts/Dex.sol

new repository and new contract code

Comment: I realized why is it causing the error :), You are implementing erc20. I did not pay attention. I thought it was just a contract with a simple functon. i will explain in solution

Comment: Sorry man but still I have Problem and I did not understand your answer.

Comment: @kianous you have to write approval mechanism first. the functions that mentioned have to be called. otherwise dex cannot reach to your contract and send money on your behalf